# Ответ от сервера как получить куки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie, get

Можно ли как нибудь получить куки отправленные ответом с сервера через JQuery ajax?

Comment: сделайте не браузерном js:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Куки

Comment: Вы можете получать куки только из запросов на тот же домен, в ином случае нужен небольшой серверный прокси-скрипт.